# PostgreSQL, how to append result to another query result

Tags: postgresql

**First Query**

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE _id = 1
```

result from query:

```
{
  username: "Test",
  nickname: "somename"
}
```

**Second Query**

```
SELECT json_object_agg(permission, true) FROM user_permissions WHERE user_id = 1
```

result from query:

```
{
  add: true,
  delete: true,
  somepermission: true
}
```

**Third Query**

```
SELECT array_agg(number) FROM user_phone_numbers WHERE user_id = 1
```

result from query:

```
[
  00000-0000-000,
  11111-1111-111
]
```

Basically I want to put the result of second and third query into first query so the final result will be

```
{
  username: "Test",
  nickname: "somename"
  customJSONPermission: {
        add: true,
        delete: true,
        somepermission: true
  },
  customerArrayPhone: [
      00000-0000-000,
      11111-1111-111
  ]
}
```

How do craft a single SQL command to handle this kind of operation. What kind of keywords or function I should look up?

Comment: Are you familiar with `JOIN`?

Comment: Hi this is not exactly JOIN right? JOIN will produce many rows. I just need one row with appended fields

Comment: I think this can help: https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put all queries in one:

```
SELECT u.username,
       u.nikname,
       (SELECT json_object_agg(permission, true) FROM user_permissions WHERE user_id = u._id) AS customJSONPermission,
       (SELECT array_agg(number) FROM user_phone_numbers WHERE user_id = u._id) AS customerArrayPhone
  FROM users AS u
 WHERE u._id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I guess this is absolutely the shortest way? What if my userobject have 100 fields must I write a really long SQL just to put u.field1, u.field2 ... u.field100?

Comment: You can use u.* if you want to get all fields in table

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!